# Using Brackets, two <scripts> not working together in html file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to start off by saying I know pretty much next to nothing when it comes to javascript, and just a little HTML/CSS. Anyways, I have an HTML file open in Brackets for a school project and I am using two  codes from w3school. They work individually, but if I have both scripts in my HTML file, only one work. I was wondering how to solve this?

These are the two codes that I want that are not working together

```
<script>
    window.onscroll = function() {
        myFunction()
    };

    var nav = document.getElementById("nav");
    var sticky = nav.offsetTop;

    function myFunction() {
        if (window.pageYOffset >= sticky) {
            nav.classList.add("sticky")
        } else {
            nav.classList.remove("sticky");
        }
    }
</script>
```

and

```
<script>
    window.onscroll = function() {
        scrollFunction()
    };

    function scrollFunction() {
        if (document.body.scrollTop > 20 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 0) {
            document.getElementById("myBtn").style.display = "block";
        } else {
            document.getElementById("myBtn").style.display = "none";
        }
    }

    function topFunction() {
        document.body.scrollTop = 0;
        document.documentElement.scrollTop = 0;
    }
</script>
```

I would like to use both of these scripts and have them work together in my html file.

Again, both codes work properly by themselves, but when I have both in my html file, only one works.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Can you add the HTML?

Comment: You're overriding the scroll event, use `window.addEventListener('scroll', ...)` instead of window.onscroll

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See a merged version of the code, although I don't know what are you doing with the `topFunction()` does not look like to be in use.

```
var nav = document.getElementById("nav");
var sticky = nav.offsetTop;
window.addEventListener('scroll', function () {
    //class list for nav element
    var navClassList = nav.classList;

    //btn
    var myBtn = document.getElementById("myBtn");

    //sticky enable
    var stickyOn = (window.pageYOffset >= sticky);

    if (stickyOn) {
        navClassList.add("sticky")
    } else {
        navClassList.remove("sticky");
    }

    //is button view port
    var isButtonViewPort = (document.body.scrollTop > 20 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 0);

    if (isButtonViewPort) {
        myBtn.style.display = "block";
    } else {
        myBtn.style.display = "none";
    }
});

function topFunction() {
    document.body.scrollTop = 0;
    document.documentElement.scrollTop = 0;
}
```

Comment: glad to be of help , do select the answer as correct. @gofish1234

Comment: There is another solution that will work better: using addEventListener. You can manage and track triggering of each listener from debugger console later

Comment: yeah @MeghdadHadidi i just did :)

Answer (score 2):

The reason only one works is that you're replacing the first assignment with the second. Since only one function can be the value of `window.onscroll` at any given time, the second assignment will always override the first. You can see this in a browser using something like the following:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
  window.onscroll = function () {
    console.log('ONE')
  }

  window.onscroll = function () {
    console.log('TWO')
  }
})
```

By using `addEventListener` you can have more than one function invoked when the event fires:

```
  window.bindEventListener('scroll', function () {
    console.log('ONE')
  }

  window.bindEventListener('scroll', function () {
    console.log('TWO')
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You are overriding scroll event of window, each time you assign a function to it.
There is two solutions:

**1-** Using addEventListener method, it add a function which you pass as second parameter, as a handler to event you pass as first parameter:

**example:**

```js
var nav = document.getElementById("nav");
var sticky = nav.offsetTop;

function myFunction() {
  if (window.pageYOffset >= sticky) {
    nav.classList.add("sticky")
  } else {
    nav.classList.remove("sticky");
  }
}

function scrollFunction() {
    if (document.body.scrollTop > 20 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 0) {
        document.getElementById("myBtn").style.display = "block";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("myBtn").style.display = "none";
    }
}

function topFunction() {
    document.body.scrollTop = 0;
    document.documentElement.scrollTop = 0;
}

// Adding each function as a handler to event listener of scroll
window.addEventListener('scroll', myFunction);
window.addEventListener('scroll', topFunction);
```

**2-** Merge two function into a single function and assign as you did before

**example:**

```js
var nav = document.getElementById("nav");
var sticky = nav.offsetTop;

function thingsToDoOnScroll() {
   // First function body
 if (window.pageYOffset >= sticky) {
    nav.classList.add("sticky")
  } else {
    nav.classList.remove("sticky");
  }
  
  // Second function body
  document.body.scrollTop = 0;
  document.documentElement.scrollTop = 0;
  
}

function scrollFunction() {
    if (document.body.scrollTop > 20 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 0) {
        document.getElementById("myBtn").style.display = "block";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("myBtn").style.display = "none";
    }
}

window.scroll = thingsToDoOnScroll;
```